# Как перезаписать путь ко всем файлам в .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Скачал бекап сайта на Laravel с хостинга на локальную машину с `OpenServer`.
Соответственно, встал вопрос с путями в файле `.htaccess`.

Текущая структура папок такова:
`D:\OpenServer\domains\local.site\web\site.ru\public_html`

Нужно чтобы при заходе на главную страницу, которой соответствует папка `local.site`, все пути к файлам брались относительно папки `\web\site.ru\public_html`.

Предполагаю, что нужно использовать правило `RewriteRule`, но не пойму как.

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^local\.site$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.local\.site$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/site.ru/public_html/
  RewriteRule (.*)   /web/site.ru/public_html/$1
```

Код отображает страницу, но не подтягивает пути к стилям и скриптам.

В `/web/site.ru/public_html/` лежит еще один `.htaccess`:

```
php_flag short_open_tag off

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
  Options -MultiViews
 </IfModule>

 RewriteEngine On

 # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

 # Handle Front Controller...
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Файлы в папке `/web/site.ru/public_html/img/` видны, но сам файл `/web/site.ru/public_html/img/visa.png` - 404 not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/site.ru/public_html/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Ваш и мой варианты показывают страницу, но не подтягивают пути к картинкам, css и js.

Comment: @АгнаманШаманский обновил ответ

Comment: так тоже не взлетело

Comment: Обнаружил, что по адресу local.site/css видно стили, но при клике на любой выводится 404 Not Found.

Comment: @АгнаманШаманский, на локальном сервере этот вариант + ваш `.htaccess` из папки `/web/site.ru/public_html/` функционируют нормально. Css файл из `/web/site.ru/public_html/css/` открывается как файл, а не ошибка ;)

Comment: @Visman Я вас не понял. Вы предлагаете  записать в /web/site.ru/public_html/.htaccess тоже самое, что и в /.htaccess?

Comment: @АгнаманШаманский, нет. Я написал как у вас есть: в корне - .htaccess от mix, в /web/site.ru/public_html/ ваш .htaccess из вопроса, который там у вас уже лежит. Обращаюсь по localhost/css/print.css, мне выдает содержимое файла из localhost/web/site.ru/public_html/css/print.css.

Comment: @Visman у меня не работает. Уже пятый час бьюсь.

Comment: @АгнаманШаманский, так может не .htaccess виноват, а Apache с его настройками. Или у вас nginx стоит перед Apache?

Comment: Проблема решена отключением nginx. Долгой Вам жизни!